# xmlstarlet to get and parse the data between tags

Tags: xmlstarlet

I wanted the get data from xml tags to script file, but data is in hexadecimal characters line(`&amp;` `&gt;`) which needs are to be converted to form (&& >).

Example:

```
<project>
<code><shell> if a &amp;&amp; b </shell></code>
</project>
```

I am able to extract tags using command

```
xmlstarlet edit --update 'project/code/shell' --value "$DATA" shell.xml > shell.sh
```

cat shell.sh

Actual:

```
if a &amp;&amp; b
```

Expected:

```
if a && b
```

How to acheive expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To unescape special XML characters:

```
echo ' if a &amp;&amp; b ' | xmlstarlet unescape
```

Output:

```
 if a && b
```

---

```
cat file.xml | xmlstarlet unescape
```

Output:

```
<project>
<code><shell> if a && b </shell></code>
</project>
```